# DateTime format - one digit day not recognized

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I need to read a String in the following format: "6102015" (meaning October 6th, 2015) and turn it into DateTime objects.

I tried the following code, which did not work:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("6102015", "dMyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

But when I tested the code using the date string with an extra 0, it worked.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06102015", "dMyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // works correctly
```

Is there a way to read this date format without having to add the 0?

I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You should *really* avoid that format. Take "1112015" as an example... is that January 11th 2015 or November 1st 2015? Just say "no" to ambiguous date/time formats... date and time code is hard enough to get right without unnecessary problems like this.

Comment: That's a good point. But since I'm merely processing someone else's database, i don't really have that choice. And I sincerely don't know what I would do if I stumbled into 1112015. :/ But thanks for the insight.

Comment: I would talk to the owner of the database and find out then - as well as making sure they realize that a) storing date/time values as strings is a bad idea when databases have native date/time types; b) using an ambiguous format is a truly horrible idea.

Comment: If your assumption is that the first one field is the day, just pad a 0 in front of it if needed and then convert it.

Comment: In short, no, you'll get a FormatException "s does not contain a valid string representation of a date and time." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to read this date format without having to add the 0?

Adding a 0 is the least of your worries, IMO. *That* takes one line of code.

Assuming you've got a copy of the database or something you can alter, effectively, I would:

1. Create a field of a date/time type, or if you *must* use a string, do so but use an ISO-8601 format (yyyy-MM-dd)
2. Parse all the values which are already 8 characters
3. Parse all the values which are 6 characters by inserting two 0s (so `abcccc` becomes `0a0bcccc`)
4. For each remaining value, of the form `abcyyyy`:

   - Try parsing it as `0abcyyyy`
   - Try parsing it as `ab0cyyyy`
   - If only one parse worked, store that result in the new column
5. Now look at all the remaining rows (i.e. the ones you haven't populated with a "known good" value

   - You *may* be able to use other data (such as insertion order) to work out which is the "right" parse...
   - You may not - in which case you need to decide what to do

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I think that's what I will do, specially beacuse I think it will be better to know how many dates are ambiguous (that is, how many dates I might have gotten wrong). Thanks again.